# What does web.config's codeBase's href element do?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

What does ASP.Net do with the href element of web.config's codeBase element?

Does it actually go out to the web address and read the file remotely?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this could help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [codeBase Element docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the href attribute:

> Specifies the URL where the runtime can find the specified version of
>   the assembly.

If the assembly is not a private assembly it can be on the Internet, so it does get the assembly from the web address. It can be a local relative path to the applications directory as well.

Comment: It raises a number of questions that I can't find the answer for. When it gets the DLL file remotely, what does it do with the copy? Does it store it in memory, as a temp file or does it write to the GAC? What happens when it can't find the file? What about security?